# Connect vb oledb with oracle over LAN

Tags: vb.net, oracle, oledbconnection

How can I connect vb.net project with oracle database over LAN network?

Server ip is `1‪92.1‪68.0‪.1‪`

Client ip is `1‪92.1‪68.0‪.2‪`

Connection string is: `oledbconnectio("provider =msdaora; datasourse=orcl; user id=ali; password=ali`)

It works well over server.

How can I modify the connection string for the client?

Comment: take a look here - https://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle/

Comment: The server IP is "hidden" in data source `orcl` - `orcl` is just an alias, the IP, port, service name etc. are defined in your `tnsnames.ora` file.

Comment: More details please... How to modify tnsname.ora .. example please